# How to parse a Zend URL for parameters?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to extract the GET parameters from a ZF REST URL. It's not the current request and I don't want to call the URL or execute the route, I just need the parameters. I'm looking for a utility function like parse_url(), but for the Zend REST format. Is there one, or do I have to reinvent the wheel?

I've tried a few things like creating a new Zend_Controller_Request_Http but the parameters aren't being populated. It is a valid HTTP URL.

Edit: Upon request, a sample Zend URL:

```
http://localhost/index/index/param1/foo/param2/bar
```

So I am just trying to get param1 and param2 out of this URL.

Edit #2: I tried this but it does not seem to work:

```
$request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http('http://localhost/home/test/param1/foo/param2/bar');
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$route = new Zend_Rest_Route($front);
var_dump($route->match($request));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about `$uri = Zend_Uri::factory( $yourUrl )`' ? See [Zend_Uri](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.uri.chapter.html).

**Edit:**
Ah, I see what you mean now. In that case I believe you should try what Gordon suggested. Run your url through the `match` method of your route.

There probably is a way to retrieve the route from the router with something like (not sure though):

```
$route = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
                              ->getRouter()
                              ->getRoute( 'theRouteName' );
```

And then do semething like:

```
$params = $route->match( $yourUrl );
```

.. which should give you an array of parameters.

Comment: That gives me a Zend_Uri object, but then what do I do with that object to get the parameters? getQuery() returns false because it only looks for a standard query string (?param1=foo&param2=bar).

Comment: Awesome. I just changed getRoute($name) to getCurrentRoute() and this solution works for me. Thanks so much!

Comment: +1. deleting mine, upvoting here. this is much more straightforward. Just a minor sidenote: match() will internally replace $yourURL with the current request object if it is not an instance of Zend_Controller_Request_Http to start with.

Answer (score 8):

If anyone came here trying to get all params (including module/controller/action) from a stored URL considering the routes defined on your routes.ini, you should:

```
/**
 * Code kept big just for example purposes
 * Creates a request object, route and injects back the properties parsed
 */
$url = 'http://www.site.com/module/controller/action/param1/test';
$request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http($url);
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->route($request);

// Module name
$request->getModuleName();

// Controller name
$request->getControllerName();

// Action name
$request->getActionName();

// All parameters
$request->getParams();
```