# splitting up the path portion of a url

Tags: php, zend-framework

i couldn't find anything so i just wanted to take a url and then split it and turn it into key value pairs.

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/var/1/var2/2';
```

i am currently using a array_chunk on the path after using a parse_url

```
$u = parse_url($url);
$decoded = array_chunk($u['path'],2);
```

but it returns

```
array (
   [0] => array (
       [0] => var
       [1] => 1
   ),
   [1] => array (
       [0] => var2
       [1] => 2
   )
)
```

what i would like is

```
array (
    [var] => 1,
    [var2] => 2
)
```

is there a Zend Framework method that is available to decode this into an array?

Comment: Probably the duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458539/how-to-parse-a-zend-url-for-parameters

Comment: @akond yes you are correct! #winning! yes i used $route =     Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
                              ->getRouter()
                              ->getCurrentRoute();


        $params = $route->match( $url );

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use request object.

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/var/1/var2/2';
$request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http($url);
$params = $request->getParams();
// or
$param = $request->getParam('var', $defaultValueNull);
```

This has the advantage, that you don't have to use `isset` to check which keys were set.

Answer (score 0):

```
$u = parse_url($url);
$decoded = array_chunk($u['path'],2);
$new = array();
for ($decoded as $pair) {
    $new[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
}
print_r($new);
```

outputs

```
array (
    [var] => 1,
    [var2] => 2
)
```

Comment: I think you mean `$new[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];`

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the Controller it's simply

```
$data = $this->_getAllParams();
unset($data['module'], $data['controller'], $data['action']);
```

$data will now be

```
array (
    [var] => 1,
    [var] => 2
)
```

Hopefully you're not POSTing variables as well or this will also include the POST'd variables.