# Getting Zend Framework URLs from a strings

Tags: php, url, zend-framework

I'm trying to convert strings to Zend Framework format URLs.

For example, I have a string list

```
http://example.com/products/category/books
http://example.com/products/category/computers
http://example.com/contact
```

I want to receive a list with Zend_Controller_Request_Http objects, where parameters like controller, action, params, etc. will be recognized.

```
Zend_Controller_Request_Http Object ( ... [_params:protected] => Array ( [controller] => index [action] => products [category] => books [module] => default ) ... )
Zend_Controller_Request_Http Object ( ... [_params:protected] => Array ( [controller] => index [action] => products [category] => computers [module] => default ) ... )
Zend_Controller_Request_Http Object ( ... [_params:protected] => Array ( [controller] => index [action] => contact ... )
```

I found some solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6032363/804578) (thanks [Willy Barro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149760/willy-barro))

```
$url = 'http://example.com/module/controller/action/param1/test';
$request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http($url);
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->route($request);

$request->getParams();
```

and it works fine for the first url, but for the rest I receive the same parameters:

```
[controller]=>index, [action]=>products, [category]=>books
[controller]=>index, [action]=>products, [category]=>books
[controller]=>index, [action]=>contact, [category]=>books
```

Looks like all I cannot change parameters at all...

Maybe there is some another way to convert string to the zf URL.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, at the moment I do not find any better solution than this:

```
$divideURL = function($url){
    $zfURL = [];
    $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http($url);
    Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->route($request)->getParams();

    $zfURL['module'] = $request->getModuleName();
    $zfURL['controller'] = $request->getControllerName();
    $zfURL['action'] = $request->getActionName();

    $url = preg_replace("/".preg_quote($this->getRequest()->getScheme() . '://' . $this->getRequest()->getHttpHost(), "/")."/", "", $url);
    $url = preg_replace("/".preg_quote("/".$zfURL['module'], "/")."/", "", $url);
    $url = preg_replace("/".preg_quote("/".$zfURL['controller'], "/")."/", "", $url);
    $url = preg_replace("/".preg_quote("/".$zfURL['action'], "/")."/", "", $url);

    $urlparts = explode("/", $url);
    for($i=1; $i<count($urlparts); $i+=2){
        if(!empty($urlparts[$i])){
            $zfURL[$urlparts[$i]] = $urlparts[$i+1];
        }
    }

    return $zfURL;
};


print_r($divideURL('http://example.com/products/category/books'));
print_r($divideURL('http://example.com/products/category/computers'));
print_r($divideURL('http://example.com/contact'));
```

Output is:

```
Array ( [module] => default [controller] => index [action] => products [category] => books )
Array ( [module] => default [controller] => index [action] => products [category] => computers )
Array ( [module] => default [controller] => index [action] => contact )
```